# Setting BarWidth In Primefaces 3.5 [BarChart]

Tags: xhtml, primefaces, bar-chart

I want to set width of bars in barchart of primefaces.I tried this extender but didn't work :

```
this.cfg.seriesDefaults = {
    rendererOptions: {
      barWidth:10  
  }
};
```

How can i handle this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You should set width of barchart dynamically by setting **style** attribute like below, component arrange bar width automatically;

**style="height:720px; width:#{statisticBean.barChartWidth}px"**

Set your barChart with on bean side by calculating barcount*barwidth+66 for example;
Use 10 for barwidth. Multiply with chartItemCount and add 66 or something for bar label width.

```
public int getBarChartWidth() {
        return chartItemCount * 10 + 66;
    }
```

Good Luck!

Answer (score 0):

In case your are still looking for a solution, I would suggest trying the following:

`this.cfg.seriesDefaults.rendererOptions= {
          barWidth:10

    };`

I slightly modified the syntax of your code. It worked fine with me.

Hope it helps.